# Test if an event listener was added in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am using react js to build my application, also for testing Enzyme and Jest. In my component i have this useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => my
    function);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', () => my
    function);
}, []);
```

I want to test 2 scenarios:

1. If the component was mounted if this event was added  `window.addEventListener('beforeunload'`, 
    2. Also, if the component was unmountet, if the event was removed  `return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload'` 
   Question: How to test these 2 scenarios? I looked over examples but there i did not find any ideas. Who faced with this?

Comment: 1. Unless you have passed the _same_ function to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` methods, event listener won't be removed. 2. You could trigger the event and test the effect of the event like some message showing up in the DOM, etc.

Comment: @Yousaf, could you show please? Will be very helpfull.

Comment: @Yousaf, but how to test these 2 scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener and removeEventListener work only with the same function reference. You have to declare the function before use it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const myFuntion = () => {...}
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', myFuntion);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', myFunction);
}, []);
```

You can see this in the official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#recap

you can verifiy registered event listener in chrome devtools like this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/get-and-debug-event-listeners

Comment: but how to test these 2 scenarios?

Comment: check this link to test in chrome : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/get-and-debug-event-listeners

Comment: there is not something related to `how to tes it using enzyme and jest`